# Property of undefined trying to loop through JSON array from MYSQL query

Tags: json, node.js, pug

I have looked at all the solutions here for the last 2 days and none of them work. I keep getting undefined properties, im so confused.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
db.query('SELECT fileName, title, description FROM uploads', function(err, results, fields) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(results);
        res.render('index', {resultJSON: results});
    }
});
```

});

console.log(results) prints out the array 
[ RowDataPacket { 
   filename: ...,
   title: ...,
   description: ...
  } 
  RowDataPacket {
   same again
  }
  RowDataPacket {
    .......
  } ]

here is my jade file

```
include includes/head.html
include includes/dsdsf.html
include includes/dsfss.html
include includes/dsffs.html

each val in resultsJSON
    p #{val.fileName}

div
    h3 edscx
```

.....
I have tried lots of random ways at accessing the stuff in resultsJSON and nothing works, currently the error is

C:\filepath...\index.jade:8 Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In `res.render()` you are setting the results in `resultJSON` but in the template you are accessing `resultsJSON`. The former is singular but the latter is plural.

Comment: wooooow, if only i had a rubber duck near me the last 2 days

Comment: Thanks aha, feel pretty stupid now